# How to put username and password to connect to remote node in the Monero v0.12.3?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, linux, remote-access

I tried to connect to my remote node from my monero gui on my linux machine. But there is no option to put in a user/pass to connect to the remote node. Also the format: user:pass@xxxx.com doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

You need to press the advanced arrow button (if I recall correctly) below the node address field to display those fields in the settings page.